# Why barcode scanner opens Chrome developer console in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, barcode, barcode-scanner

I just bought a barcode reader from China model Honeywell HH400. It works perfectly when I use it other device. But now I use it in my web application and I am getting a problem. It always toggle Chrome developer console. I also tried scanning barcode into URL bar, and it does the same. Does it have an event to trigger F12 what? Or misconfiguration with the scanner that I don't know?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that you might have already received a solution.
But for others who might come across this issue,

I ran into this problem today and found that no matter what prefix or suffix I try, on every browser it emulates pressing F12 which opens the browser console.

The same barcode functioned as required a couple of weeks ago.

Every barcode comes with a quick start guide that you can use to set prefix suffix etc. 
[image: Image for Prefix Suffix]

There is also a bar code that "Recalls Defaults". Just scan that and you should have the factory defaults set. 
[image: Image of the barcode for Recall Defaults]

This resolved my issue. 
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I have the same issue but I cannot see the "solution" in your answer ?! I removed all suffixes but it still seems to send the "F12" command after every scan.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to remove the "Line Feed" suffix ( which was not removed when I scanned the "remove all suffixes" code ), as the line feed is interpreted as CRTL-J on windows machines ... no idea why !?
( no time to research it either ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with same mentioned model.
The solution was to scan the Enable CR Suffix, and scan the Disable LF Suffix
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R69J.jpg)